# How do I create an edit function inside of a list?

Tags: javascript

[Currently I have a delete function already which is shown by a cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFKrs.png)

So how I am doing this is by using a function that renders in the information from another database, into this list.

```
function renderCafe(doc){
let li = document.createElement('li');
let name = document.createElement('span');
let city = document.createElement('span');
let cross = document.createElement('div');

li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
name.textContent = doc.data().name;
city.textContent = doc.data().city;
cross.textContent = 'x';

li.appendChild(name);
li.appendChild(city);
li.appendChild(cross);  

cafeList.appendChild(li);

// deleting data
cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    db.collection('cafes').doc(id).delete();
});}
```

So how do I create the edit button function like this delete one? Should it also be an EventListener that occurs when clicked?

> I was thinking to have an edit button, when clicked, changes into "Update",  while the static information turns into a text box with the current values.
>
> Then when the "Update" is being clicked, it then saves the information.

I am a student, and have no prior knowledge in javascript, i took these codes from tutorials that I can find online.

Comment: You will need to introduce 2 more event handlers. `click` for the edit option and the `change` handler when you update the text in the input ( which will then make a request to update the text )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, similar to your style.

Replace the `alert` with a database update.

Make sure you're listening for document changes, and updating your UI accordingly, so that the new name and city will replace your old ones.

```js
const cafeList = document.getElementById('cafe-list');

const sampleCafes = [
{ data: () => ({ name: 'new cafe', city: 'new city'}), id: 'sample-cafe' },
];

sampleCafes.forEach(cafe => renderCafe(cafe));

function renderCafe(doc){
let li = document.createElement('li');
let name = document.createElement('p');
let city = document.createElement('p');
let nameInput = document.createElement('input');
let cityInput = document.createElement('input');
let edit = document.createElement('div');
let submit = document.createElement('div');
let cross = document.createElement('div');

li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
name.textContent = doc.data().name;
city.textContent = doc.data().city;
nameInput.value = name.textContent;
cityInput.value = city.textContent;
nameInput.hidden = true;
cityInput.hidden = true;
edit.textContent = 'edit';
submit.textContent = 'submit';
submit.hidden = true;
cross.textContent = 'x';

li.appendChild(name);
li.appendChild(city);
li.appendChild(nameInput);
li.appendChild(cityInput);
li.appendChild(edit);
li.appendChild(submit);
li.appendChild(cross);  

cafeList.appendChild(li);

// deleting data
cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    alert(`db.collection('cafes').doc(id).delete();`);
});

// editing data
edit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    nameInput.hidden = false;
    cityInput.hidden = false;
    submit.hidden = false;
    name.hidden = true;
    city.hidden = true;
    edit.hidden = true;
});

// submitting new data
submit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    nameInput.hidden = true;
    cityInput.hidden = true;
    submit.hidden = true;
    name.hidden = false;
    city.hidden = false;
    edit.hidden = false;
    const newName = nameInput.value;
    const newCity = cityInput.value;
    alert(`TODO: update doc '${id}' to\n{name: '${newName}', city: '${newCity}'}.`);
});
}
```

```html
<ul id="cafe-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Awesome code reference, modified here and there and managed to perform the edit function successfully. Thank you so much @Stratubas

Comment: Hi @Stratubas, could I ask, why isnt the some fields hiding? Such as the name, city and edit, despite having them set as name.hidden = true; already?

Comment: @BasirLa Hello again. Are you sure you're making the correct elements hidden? Can you post your code?

Comment: @BasirLa I mean it's possible that along the way you've changed which elements are referred to as "name", "city" etc...

Comment: I am using a certain project folder just to test these, so i did not and its not hiding for me

Comment: @Basir La you can try to make a similar project in stackblitz (include only what's necessary to show your problem) so we can really see what's wrong

Comment: @BasirLa you can also open Chrome dev tools to see if your code actually makes your item hidden. You can also try something different, like adding a border, or changing text color, to see if you're really accessing the correct element